# Postfix Body Checks Regex Example Needed

Tags: regex, postfix-mta

Postfix and Regex Experts:

I have a requirement to use Postfix Body Checks to add an empty alt="" parameter to an image link in the body of outgoing emails.  (I have no control on the generation of the image link.)  Here is an exerpt of the email body:

```
<img src=3D"http://xxxxxxx.com:81/OT000001MQ=3D=3D.GIF?D=3D2016-03-23" wid=
th=3D"1" height=3D"1"/>
```

I need Postfix Body Check to add and empty alt parameter `alt=3D""` to this link for improving SPAM test score.

I do succeed with this Body Check Regex, but it's an ugly solution:

```
/height=3D"1"/  REPLACE th=3D"1" height=3D"1" alt=3D""/>
```

My regex is selecting the entire line of the body text.  Could you please suggest a better regex?  Thank you.

Comment: As far as I understand are you trying to do [this kind of replacement?](https://regex101.com/r/gS9xR4/2)

Comment: Does that solves your problem ?

Comment: I'm still grappling with it.  Postfix doesn't seem to take the /s modifier or whatever the reason.  The tool you showed me is great.  Thank you.

Comment: These pixels are for tracking and they not always come with `height=3D"13D"`, they may have different values in both `height` and `width`. May you want to scan for `src=3D"http` instead to catch all external references as ANY external reference can act as a "beacon". EDIT: Sorry for digging up an old post. I have a similar issue here but I want to get rid of the entire `img` tag, if an external reference is given.

Comment: @Roland that would be simpler. `/<img [^>]+http[^>]+>/ REPLACE ""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"My regex is selecting the entire line of the body text." If you mean you don't want to write the whole line in your replacement text, you can do that using [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html):

```
/(.* height=3D"1")(.*)/ REPLACE $1 alt=3D"" $2
```

You can see this technique used in the first example on [the man page](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html), which uses `$2` and `$4`. This should work with both [basic](http://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html) and [PCRE](http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html) regular expressions.

This is not a very precise match though; anything that specifies `height="1"` in its HTML will be caught and altered. Matching on the URL of the specific image would be a better choice.

Comment: Result: `/(.* height=3D"1")(\/>)/ REPLACE $1 alt=3D""$2`  Thank you.  I understand your advice and cannot see a way for the rule to be limited to the sender.  I think collateral damage with this hack should be nill.